# Links opening when tried in browser but not when using urlopen

Tags: python, urllib2

I tried this:

```
a = 'http://www.deanfoods.com/media/42118/deanfoodsannualreport_2009.pdf#page=32'
r = urllib2.urlopen(a)
```

Gives an error:

```
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

But when I try this in the browser the link works. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: whats your environment? it works perfectly here on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I am using MACOS 10.6.8 and Python 2.6